# Android options menu not showing and only one Share item shown

Tags: android

I'm doing my first options menu and it is not showing. Instead, when touching the options phone button on the bottom left it displays a one item menu: 'Share'.

Even if I remove the 'Share' item from my menu, it still is the only one that shows. That tells me my menu is being ignored.

I'm using the following sdks:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Here is my menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_copy"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_content_copy"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_copy"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/help"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

The Eclipse IDE shows no error in it. The strings and drawables have been defined.

I instantiate the menu so:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

For now, the handlers are empty:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_copy:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_share:
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this work:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

Write me if it works ;)

Comment: I used your code and it's exactly the same display, no changes whatsoever.

Comment: Change all the 
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
in :
    android:showAsAction="always"

This should work.

Comment: With "always" nothing shows up. No menu, not one item.

Comment: sorry sorry....my fault!I wanted to write ´never´ instead of ´always´.
Tell me if now works because I have the same as you and it works perfectly.

Comment: With only these two attributes android:id and android:title it works fine. I'm now investigating what was wrong.

Comment: It works without the showAsAction attributes. It also works with the showAsAction attributes when these all have the value "never". Strange stuff.

Comment: Only to be sure of one thing.Have you tried

    app:showAsAction="always"

instead of 

    android:showAsAction="always"?

Comment: Yes I tried and it then does not display anything at all, no menu, not even one menu item.

Comment: Have a look here: 
    http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html